# I installed kotlin from github but it is not working in cmd

Tags: java, kotlin

I downloaded the kotlin compiler from its github site (version 1.3.72) and i have java jdk version 13.0.2. I have put both in the path in environment variables in my pc but its still giving me an error. The java jdk is working fine and i can run java programs fine but the kotlin commands are not recognized by cmd. when i type kotlinc -version in cmd, i get:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader
```

I have Windows 10 (64 bit). I am trying to install kotlin so that I can run it in VS code. But if the kotlinc command is not being recognized then I cant do anything futher.

In my path variable, I put:

```
D:\Setups and Installers\Kotlin 1.3.72\kotlinc\bin
```

which is where I installed the kotlin compiler from github.

Answer (score 2):

[The Kotlin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin) github can give you some pointer.

In the prerequisiste it said you need java 1.8 and JDK 9 installed

But you Have the JDK 13

Which can explain the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows, in my case the error was happening because the kotlin compiler folder was not on the system's main hard drive, I simply put it on the main hard drive and added it to the system environment variables.